# C# PDFSharp - Add black underline to separate text

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm using PDFSharp to create a PDF in C# and I want to add a black underline between two blocks of text, like this:
[image]

This is (part) of the code I'm using to write my PDF:

```
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(); 
        PdfPage page = pdf.AddPage();
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        XFont title = new XFont("Times New Roman", 30, XFontStyle.Bold);
        XFont formatBody = new XFont("Times New Roman", 15);

        XImage image = XImage.FromFile("Logo.png");

        gfx.DrawString("Text Title", title, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(0, 75, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
         
        //LINE SEPARATOR HERE

        gfx.DrawString("Body text", formatBody, XBrushes.Black,
            new XRect(50, 130, page.Width, page.Height), XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a line is simple:

```
gfx.DrawLine(XPens.DarkGreen, 0, 120, page.Width, 0);
```

The PDFsharp samples are explained here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Draw_simple_lines_0

Sample source code can be found here:
https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp-samples